# Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 Ubuntu

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, xampp, lamp

I am new to Ubuntu and I am trying to run mysql using xampp. Earlier xampp was run successfully and able to run mysql as well. But suddenly when I trying to start it was stopping and it will display an error message on log saying "do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306". So I tried to kill the running process of mysql using following command but even that process was get killed, there will be another new process of mysql running when I rerun the following command.

`pidof mysqld`

`sudo kill -9 <pid>`

I tried to kill all the processes running on port 3306 as well. But same result happened. Where I was get wrong and how to resolve this?

Comment: Ubuntu has mysql and all the components of XAMPP installed. What value is it offering? You could just use ubuntu. The systemd service that managed mysqld restarted mysql when is killed.

Answer (score 2):

`sudo lsof -i TCP:3306' and`sudo kill ` commands worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

you can try "netstat -anltp" to find See if 3306 port still being used